# Why my clearInterval in React doesn't work?

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, intervals

when I click to to change code I see inly consols.log. I try to understand it but I can't find the answer..

```js
function App() {
  const [laps, setLaps] = useState(0);
  const [running, setRunning] = useState(false);
  const startTime = Date.now() - laps;

   useEffect(() => {
    function interval() {
      setInterval(() => {
        setLaps(Date.now() - startTime);
      }, 100);
    }

    if (!running) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      console.log('ok');
    } else {
      interval();
      console.log('no');
    }
    console.log(running);
  }, [running]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <label>Count: {laps}</label>
        <button onClick={() => setRunning(!running)}>{running ? 'stop' : 'start'}</button>
        <button>Clear</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In clean JavaScript this code should works correctly(of course without  JSX)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clearInterval` expects a number as argument that is returned from `setInterval`, but you are giving it the `interval` function as argument.

You could instead just create the interval if `running` is true, and return a cleanup function from `useEffect` that will be run the next time the effect is run.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [laps, setLaps] = useState(0);
  const [running, setRunning] = useState(false);
  const startTime = Date.now() - laps;

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (running) {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          setLaps(Date.now() - startTime);
        }, 100);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
      }
    },
    [running]
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>Count: {laps}</label>
      <button onClick={() => setRunning(!running)}>
        {running ? "stop" : "start"}
      </button>
      <button>Clear</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```